# Is \obeylines no longer a valid instruction in a LaTeX document?

Tags: errors

Background information on my computing setup: MacBook Air (late-2019 model), MacOS 11.2.3 "Big Sur", MacTeX2021 with all updates current.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\obeylines
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

It (unsurprisingly) compiles fine under pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX. In contrast, if one removes the `%` comment character before `\obeylines`, one gets the following error messages:

- Under pdfLaTeX:

  ```
  ...
  (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
  ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
  <to be read again> 
                     ^^M
  l.29   {l3backend-pdftex.def}{2021-03-18}{}
  ```
- Under XeLaTeX:

  ```
  (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
  ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
  <to be read again> 
                     ^^M
  l.29   {l3backend-xetex.def}{2021-03-18}{}
  ```
- Under LuaLaTeX:

  ```
  ...
  (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
  ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
  <to be read again> 

  l.29   {l3backend-luatex.def}{2021-03-18}{}
  ```

  Observe: no `^^M` in the LuaLaTeX error message, unlike with the pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Aside: The Plain-TeX test document

```
\obeylines
abc
\bye
```

compiles fine under pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LauTeX.

**Question:** Is this a bug? A feature? Are there any known work-arounds? FWIW: I'm sure the test program compiles fine under MacTeX2020.

Comment: `\obeylines` is not really a preamble command.  Best case scenario it will mess up reading the `.aux` file at `\begin{document}`, so if it worked before I'd say it was by accident

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik - Thanks for this. I wasn't aware of the fact one shouldn't use `\obeylines` in the preamble of a LaTeX document.

Comment: In this case the `l3backend` files could be changed to cope with that setting (adding two `%` at the end of the first two non-comment lines), and this MWE will work again, but I'd advise you to not trust that other code will be so tolerant.  As a rule of thumb catcode changes (and in this case `\endlinechar` changes) should better be restricted to the document body (and preferrably enclosed in a group)

Comment: if you set it in the preamble then you are making the end of line in any package loaded or any files loaded at begin document active. If things work then that's by luck not planning

Comment: In a similar context `luatex` doesn't show `^^M` as the token to be read again, which seems a “feature”.

Comment: @egreg I _think_ that's because `luatex` renders the actual ASCII 13 on the terminal, rather than the `^^M` notation (which is not too helpful in this case)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik On the other hand, if I assign ``\catcode`\^^M=15``, the error message shows `^^M` as the invalid character also with `luatex`.

Comment: AFAIK `\obeylines` is npt documented in the LaTeX manual or the companion or any other official documentation. So it isn't a LaTeX command.

Comment: @MartinSchröder - Thanks. `\obeylines` *is* defined in `latex.ltx` (in a way that's entirely analogous to its definition on p. 352 of the TeXbook); does that make it a LaTeX command? Anyway, as Phelype and others have already shown, the issue I was stumbling over was caused by me improperly running `\obeylines` in the preamble instead of in the body of `document` environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Community Answer based on the Comments*

The command `\obeylines` must be used **after `\begin{document}`** and *not* before `\begin{document}`.

### Background

> You may have several consecutive lines of input for which you want the
> output to appear line-for-line in the same way. One solution is to
> type `\par` at the end of each input line; but that’s somewhat of a
> nuisance, so **plain TeX provides** the abbreviation **`\obeylines`**, which
> causes each **end-of-line** in the input to **be like `\par`**. After you say
> `\obeylines` you will get one line of output per line of input, unless
> an input line ends with `%` or unless it is so long that it must be
> broken. For example, you probably want to use `\obeylines` if you are
> typesetting a poem. Be sure to enclose `\obeylines` in a group, unless
> you want this "poetry mode" to continue to the end of your document.
>
> *TeXBook at page 94*

### Correct

**Version 1**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\obeylines % :)

Word
Word

\end{document}
```

**Version 2**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% Alternative :)
% https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12340
\begin{obeylines}
Word
Word
\end{obeylines}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Not Correct

```
\documentclass{article}

\obeylines % :(
\begin{document}

Word
Word

\end{document}
```

> ```
> <to be read again> 
>                    \scan_stop: 
> l.29   {l3backend-pdftex.def}{2021-07-12}{}
>                                            
> The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
> not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
> ```

[image]

### Related

- [Is there a counterpart/antidote for \obeylines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57318)
- https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12340
- [Plain TeX macros contains \par as parameter delimiter, but doesn't work with \obeylines, why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108940)

Comment: it does not seem to work in beamer